# R group by error

Tags: r

Want to run

```
data_visit %>%
  group_by(post_pagename) %>%
    summarize(n_unique = n_distinct(visit_id))
```

But get error:

> Fehler in group_by(., post_pagename) : 
>         konnte Funktion "group_by" nicht finden

Could not find group_by

Have installed dplyr and magrittr.

```
Library(dplyr)
```

results in:

> Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>   Namensraum ‘rlang’ 0.1.6 ist bereits geladen, aber >= 0.2.0 wird gefordert
>   Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
>   Paket ‘dplyr’ wurde unter R Version 3.4.4 erstellt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update the `rlang` package.